# Secure and "squarified" photo uploading in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I'm building a website for a club, and I'd like each member to be able to upload a profile photo.

I've seen a few questions and answers on SO about the basics of how to do this, but I'm concerned about two things that are a little bit more challenging:

1. **Security** - I want to prevent people from uploading files that are not valid images and/or contain malicious content.
2. **Uniformity** - I want files to be of a reasonable size and images to be square. I would like to provide a UI to help the user crop the photo into a square once the photo has been uploaded and verified.

Ideally, I'd like to find a free/open-source utility that I can just plug in to my app and go. If there's nothing like that available, I'd appreciate advice and/or sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any plug-in utility to help you. Best would be to just build something yourself. Here are two blog articles that could help you to easily create your own validator:

- [How to Securely Verify and Validate Image Uploads in ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/06/24/How-to-Securely-Verify-and-Validate-Image-Uploads-in-ASPNET-and-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)
- [Image Upload & Validation with ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.blog.gankiewicz.eu/post/2011/07/09/Simple-Image-Upload-Validation-with-ASPNET-MVC-3.aspx)
- [Image Upload, Crop and Resize with ASP.NET MVC jQuery Uploadify and jCrop](http://www.schnieds.com/2011/07/image-upload-crop-and-resize-with.html)

Comment: +1. This helps with the security aspect. I'm still looking for a solution to resize the photos and help users crop them into a square.

Comment: I've added a link in my answer which explains how to use the Jcrop jQuery plugin with ASP.NET MVC. It's a nice plugin to crop images. A ratio (so 1:1 for your square) can also be set.
Also, uploadify is a nice jQuery upload helper which I've used before and works pretty well.